# Where can I read more about procedurally generated levels?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'd like to make a little game in my off-time, and I want it to have a procedurally-generated world. I'm not going to ask you guys to do my research for me, and I already have some ideas on how I'd do it, but if anyone can point me to some reading material for already-known methods, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try out Wave Function Collapse.
There is a pretty good documentation and possible for 2D and 3D.

https://robertheaton.com/2018/12/17/wavefunction-collapse-algorithm/ by Robert Heaton